# Does mplfinance support multiple figures

Tags: plot, charts, figure, mplfinance

I have an mplfinance question. I would like to have any number of figures on which the panels method can be used. In others words a figure per ticker. This would allow me to assign different studies to each unique ticker and also be able to position each figure and give this capability to the user as well.

It is not clear to me where to start as the documentation for the panels method and external axes method does not appear to support this for example I have not seen the use of the num parameter which is used in pyplot to set the current figure.